# How to find out the HTTP method of the current request?

Tags: perl, mason

I have no idea how to get the HTTP headers with Mason. I only know that $m is the Mason Request Class.

Comment: You might need to install an optional module to have syntactically sweetened easy access (`HTML::Mason::Devel`?) or, as @putanmhill siggests, somehow read it from the "frontend" (the server process that is using Mason) environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mason itself doesn't deal with HTTP as it is essentially just a templating system. The HTTP transport would be handled by `Plack` through say `Poet` or `Catalyst`, and that's where you should obtain the headers from. But as you haven't mentioned what you're using alongside of Mason, I can't tell you where to look.